# Platform Developer II Certification: Aura going away?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, certification

I'm working toward my [Platform Developer II certification](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/credentials/platformdeveloperii), and am looking for some insight about how the exam may or may not be evolving re: Aura vs. LWC.

I have completed my Apex Specialist and Data Integration Specialist superbadges.  Last night I was about to start looking at the [Aura Components Specialist](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_lcf), which is currently the next prerequisite before I can complete the [Advanced Apex Specialist superbadge](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_aap), which in turn is the last prerequisite before I can sit for the exam.  But now I see this on the Advanced Apex Specialist superbadge page:

> Additional Note
>
> We're hard at work bringing you updated superbadge
> content that reflects product enhancements and industry best
> practices. As a result, one prerequisite for this superbadge, Aura
> Components Specialist, will be removed as of October 11, 2021. If you
> have already unlocked this superbadge or unlock it before October 11,
> you won't experience any changes. If you've already started the Aura
> Components Specialist Superbadge and wish to earn it prior to its
> retirement, make sure to complete it before October 11, 2021.

Are Aura skills still a key component of Platform Developer II certification? Is there any indication that the content of this certification has been or will soon be modified to remove/replace the Aura skills component?

Comment: That depends on what your goals are. Do you have time to do both? Do you foresee yourself doing Aura work in the future (Aura isn't "going away" any time soon, as far as I can tell, you might need some knowledge on it)? Do you want the extra trailhead points that the superbadge offers, which, once permanently removed, won't be accessible to you? This question is likely to be based on opinion rather than fact, though I'm not going to VTC (but others might).

Comment: For simplicity's sake, let's just say my goal is to take the shortest possible path to certification. In the interest of passing the exam, I would like to complete the most relevant superbadges that will shore up the skills I should expect to need.